# json array returns, but can't use the response to access it

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I have been trying to fetch a json array from an external page. Even though it shows in the browser's element inspector, I can't use it in the console or in my code.

jquery code:

```
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  dataType:"json",
  url:"datacenter.php",
  success:function(data){
    console.log(data.codeName);
  },error:function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

php code:

```
<?php header('Content-type: application/json'); ?>
insight = {
  "code":"v34ns",
  "codeName":["sureman","greatboy","namely"]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do everything inside the php tags. You also need to echo json

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
//$ makes it a variable
$insight = array(
    "code"=>"v34ns",
    "codeName"=>["sureman","greatboy","namely"]
);
echo json_encode($insight);
?>
```

Now in your JS you need to parse the encoded json

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    dataType:"json",
    url:"datacenter.php",
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data.codeName);
    },error:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1:var obj = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: your php code worked alright and not the js, but i want to tick this for the correct answer, thank you.

Comment: I was trying to test it. Glad you solved the issue. Not sure why you don't need to parse.

Answer (score 0):

console print data as string use [json.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) function

```
success:function(data){
var res = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(res.codeName);
```

Comment: 'JSON.parse(data)' logged :Unexpected token o